# Can't write a file

Tags: android, file, android-logcat

My application is about the read logcat and when the buffer will have 5000 chars write in a file, my application no throws exceptions but don't write the file.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView_mensajesAlUsuario);
        text.setText(String.valueOf(3));
         new HiloEnSegundoPlano().execute("", "", " ");

    }

    private class HiloEnSegundoPlano extends AsyncTask<String ,String,String> {

        public HiloEnSegundoPlano(){
            //TODO código del constructor
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            InputStream in = null;
            Process process = null;
            String cadena = "";
            char caracter;
            FileUtilities file = new FileUtilities(MainActivity.this);

            try {
                process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v("ALERTA",e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            in = process.getInputStream();

            while(true){
                Log.v("CONTROL", "EN EL HILO");
                try {
                    caracter = (char) in.read();
                    cadena += caracter;
                    if(cadena.length() > 5000) {
                        writeFile("LogCat", cadena);
                        break;
                    }

                        Log.v("ALERTA", String.valueOf(cadena.length()));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... t) {
            text.setText(t[0]);
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String t) {

        }
        public void writeFile(String nombre, String cadena){

            try
            {
                File ruta_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

                File f = new File(ruta_sd.getAbsolutePath()+"/Download", nombre+".txt");

                Log.v("WRITE", ruta_sd.getAbsolutePath()+"/Download");

                OutputStreamWriter fout =
                        new OutputStreamWriter(
                                new FileOutputStream(f));

                fout.write(cadena);
                fout.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.e("Ficheros", "Error al escribir fichero a tarjeta SD Ruta: "+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
            }

        }

    }
```

This is the most important part of the code.

Comment: did you try flushing it? `fout.flush()` and why is a `,` in your path?

Comment: Did you set `uses-permission`? That is **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />** in your `Manifest`.

Comment: fout.write(cadena);
fout.flush();
fout.close();
do first flush and then close
also check permission in menifest.

Comment: yes, i set "uses-permission" , my path dont have a ","  i do that ( fout.flush) and nothing

Comment: The loop will never stop if the number of characters remains under 5000, will it? It keeps reading while getting eof.

Comment: when "cadena" is less 5000 the loop only read the buffer of logcat, when "cadena" its equal to 5000 or more, write file and execute "break" the loop end

Comment: `Log.v("CONTROL", "EN EL HILO");` You should see that in your lof for every character read. How often do you see it?

Comment: `catch (IOException e)`. You have that twice in your code but are not logging it. Do it. And if there is a catch you just continu with your code as if nothing has happened. Instead you should stop/return.

Comment: `Log.v("ALERTA", String.valueOf(cadena.length()));`. You should see that too for every character read. 5000 times! Now tell what you see.

Comment: you are focus on the read buffer and that its no the problem, the problem is I can't write file on SD/Internal Memory, the final app will filter log (logcat -s "tag")